# How to Convert UTC time to PST time in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime, dateformatter

i am using react js and i am trying to convert UTC time to PST time but it is not converting according to online compilers.

**Code:**

```js
const dateString = "12/18/2023, 8:00:00";
const utcDate = new Date(dateString);
const utcMilliseconds = utcDate.getTime();
const pstMilliseconds = utcMilliseconds - 8 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
const pstDate = new Date(pstMilliseconds);
const formattedPST = pstDate.toLocaleString("en-US", {
  timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles", // Set the time zone to PST
  hour12: true,
  year: "numeric",
  month: "numeric",
  day: "numeric",
  hour: "numeric",
  minute: "numeric",
  second: "numeric",
});

console.log(formattedPST);
```

**OUTPUT:**

12/17/2023, 10:30:00 AM

but this is the expected PST Converted time

[image]

Please help how to convert UTC Time Format to PST Time Format

Thanks

Comment: my output is `12/17/2023, 5:00:00 AM` - but then, my timezone isnt' UTC+5:30

Comment: Without any indication of time zone in the source string, it is assumed to represent local time. You should also be careful with the format of the string you're parsing which should ideally conform to ISO-8601 i.e. `2023-12-18T08:00:00Z` which includes the GMT/UTC/Zulu Time zone indicator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assuming

```
const dateString = "12/18/2023, 8:00:00";
const utcDate = new Date(dateString);
```

will give you 8AM on the 18th Dec 2023 UTC

It doesn't

it gives you 8AM on the 18th Dec 2023 in YOUR timezone

the code below should work properly - up to you to convert the string you have to a ISO date string to use in `new Date` (easy string manipulation though)

```js
const dateString = "2023-12-18T08:00:00Z";
const utcDate = new Date(dateString);
const formattedPST = utcDate.toLocaleString("en-US", {
  timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles", // Set the time zone to PST
  hour12: true,
  year: "numeric",
  month: "numeric",
  day: "numeric",
  hour: "numeric",
  minute: "numeric",
  second: "numeric",
});

console.log(formattedPST);
```

Note: you don't need to add/subtract any hours/minutes from the date, because the date will now be correct, you just need to display the date in your chosen timezone, and `.toLocaleString` will do the heavy lifting for you

Comment: seems i have issue with line charts where i feed the dates to chart and in the dataFormatter i am getting as timestamps

Comment: @HarishMahi - those words mean nothing in the context of your question or this answer

Answer (score 2):

`new Date(dateString);` is **not** UTC, but your local time.

You need to use `Date.UTC(2023, 11, 18, 8, 0, 0, 0)` instead. And `toLocaleString` does not require any conversions of time.

Please see [Date.UTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC)

```js
const utcDate = new Date(Date.UTC(2023, 11, 18, 8, 0, 0, 0));
const formattedPST = utcDate.toLocaleString("en-US", {
  timeZone: "America/Los_Angeles", // Set the time zone to PST
  hour12: true,
  year: "numeric",
  month: "numeric",
  day: "numeric",
  hour: "numeric",
  minute: "numeric",
  second: "numeric",
});

console.log(formattedPST);
```

Comment: FYI: months are 0-based.

Comment: @Reyno Ups, fixed :D